# can't build the app in react-native after installing dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hi i recently installed react-navigation and the related dependecies like react-native-screens and react-native-gesture-hander and etc. but
after that my app doens't build and i always get the following error which says that the build has failed,some said that it was a proxy issue, i tried turning off proxy and using diffenret proxies from different providers but that didn't help either:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1001 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugRFile FAILED
37 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 35 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_masked-view:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_masked-view > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.0
      > Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2/appcompat-1.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2/appcompat-1.0.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2/appcompat-1.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2/appcompat-1.0.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_masked-view > androidx.core:core:1.0.0
      > Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.0.0/versionedparcelable-1.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.0.0/versionedparcelable-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.0.0/versionedparcelable-1.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.0.0/versionedparcelable-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 30s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_masked-view:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_masked-view > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.0
      > Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2/appcompat-1.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2/appcompat-1.0.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2/appcompat-1.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2/appcompat-1.0.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_masked-view > androidx.core:core:1.0.0
      > Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.0.0/versionedparcelable-1.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.0.0/versionedparcelable-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.0.0/versionedparcelable-1.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.0.0/versionedparcelable-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 30s

    at makeError (C:\Users\MMD\Desktop\Projects\awesomeproject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\MMD\Desktop\Projects\awesomeproject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16   
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\MMD\Desktop\Projects\awesomeproject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\MMD\Desktop\Projects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)     
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

and here is my app's package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "awesomeproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your package json

Comment: just added the package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `jetifier` in your `package.json` `devDependencies` and run `npm install` or `yarn install`

After installation finishes then inside the `scripts` object of `package.json` add `"postinstall": "jetify"` and run `npm install`/`yarn install`.

`postinstall` on `package.json` runs whatever command you want after `npm install` or `yarn install`, in this case it runs `jetify` and prepares the project for Android X.